# How to extend IWebElement interface to add a new method

Tags: c#, selenium, interface, extends, staleelementreferenceexception

I am trying to extend the interface `IWebElement` in C# to add a new method to protect against `StaleElementReferenceException`.

The method I want to add is a simple `retryingClick` that will try to click the WebElement up to three times before giving up:

```
public static void retryingClick(this IWebElement element)
    {
        int attempts = 0;

        while (attempts <= 2)
        {
            try
            {
                element.Click();
            }
            catch (StaleElementReferenceException)
            {
                attempts++;
            }
        }
    }
```

The reason to add the method is that our webpage makes extensive use of jQuery and a lot of elements are dynamically created/destroyed, so adding protection for each `WebElement` becomes a huge ordeal.

So the question becomes: how should I implement this method so the interface `IWebElement` can always make use of it?

Thank you,
Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that reaches the has the same question, here is how I fixed it:

Create a new `static class` ExtensionMethods:

---

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{

    public static bool RetryingClick(this IWebElement element)
    {
        Stopwatch crono = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        while (crono.Elapsed < TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60))
        {
            try
            {
                element.Click();
                return true;
            }
            catch (ElementNotVisibleException)
            {
                Logger.LogMessage("El elemento no es visible. Reintentando...");
            }
            catch (StaleElementReferenceException)
            {
                Logger.LogMessage("El elemento ha desaparecido del DOM. Finalizando ejecución");
            }

            Thread.Sleep(250);
        }

        throw new WebDriverTimeoutException("El elemento no ha sido clicado en el tiempo límite. Finalizando ejecución");
    }
}
```

---

This should be enough for the method `RetryingClick` to appear as a method for the IWebElement type

If you have any doubts, check the [Microsoft C# Programing guide for Extension Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods)

Hope this helps